# What is netbeans platform?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

Some people talk about netbeans platform! What is it? Is it the same netbeans ide or It's different? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think the official site covers it great:

> The NetBeans Platform is a broad Swing-based framework on which you
>   can base large desktop applications. The IDE itself is based on the
>   NetBeans Platform. The Platform contains APIs that simplify the
>   handling of windows, actions, files, and many other things typical in
>   applications.

From here: [Netbeans Platform Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html)

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading the wiki entry and then ask specific questions if you don't understand:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

I can say, roughly, Netbeans Platform is the future of Graphical User Interface (GUI). Designing everything from scratch is no longer an option. It combines the power of Java code, flexibility of swing, and the knowledge of Netbeans' developers. With this modular platform you can build your application on top of Netbeans IDE. To be more clear, Imagine, you want to design an interface for a wordprocessor application, what you need in you application in terms of user interaction, is already available as well-developed packages, what you have to "add" is your specific classes and, what you want to learn is how to integrate you classes in the Netbeans Platform. This gives a high level flexibility and re-usability.

To sum it all up, you customize the netbeans IDE and the developed packages to fit your application. Starting by a skeletal interface and ended by specialized GUI as well as a an efficient application if your specialized classes were well written.
Please have a look at this crash course example:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-htmleditor.html

Regards